# Adding a view to a LinearLayout at a specified position

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have the following main.xml file with a LinearLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="1" android:id="@+id/llid">
    <TextView android:text="Client profile"
    android:id="@+id/ProfileName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    </TextView>    
    <TextView android:text="Specs"
    android:id="@+id/Specs"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I add an image to the LinearLayout via code at runtime like so

```
            ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
            image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llid);
            ll.addView(image);
```

However, I want to add the ImageView between the 2 TextViews in my LinearLayout. I can't seem to find a way in the android docs to add a view before another view, or after. How can I do this?

**NB** I call

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

**Before** I add the ImageView to the LinearLayout.

Comment: Why do you want to do so? Just declare imageview in layout and set source to it instead of inserting imageview in code.

Comment: This won't work. At runtime I am loading an image dynamically and want to display it in my layout.

Comment: You can set source for ImageView dynamically. I really don't see the reason to do in the way you describe.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

When adding a `View` to a `ViewGroup`, you can [specify an index](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int%29) which sets the position of the view in the parent.

You have two views and so (counting from zero) you would want to add at the 1st position; just call `ll.addView(image, 1);` to have it placed in between the two `TextViews`.

Comment: I was wondering what if I have two views and I want the first one to take more than half of my layout and the other one only small space of my layout how I can do that ? and can I used this with other layouts like relative layout for example

Comment: I came here looking to learn how to add a `View` to a specific location relative to another child `View` to be dynamically determined. I realize the question doesn't directly ask that, so rather than make my own answer, I'll just add to this one how one would do that: first use `ViewGroup.indexOfChild(View view)` to get the index of the other `View`, then use the `addView` method with the index detailed here to insert a new `View` relative to an existing one.

Comment: @TimM. Dude, thanks a lot. I was looking exactly for that.

Answer (score 11):

The docs state you can use the index to insert it where you want.  I see you are using the signature of the view only, did you try the signature with the index parameter?

```
public void addView(View child, int index)
```

Comment: I have indexoutofbound error while inserting textview to layout.It only explains index=2,count=0.....

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar problem. In my case I wanted to add a LinearLayout at last position of another LinearLayout. To accomplish it, I did:

```
LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

// add others views to your linear layout

parentLayout.addView(layout, parentLayout.getChildCount());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);

ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagefield);
img.setImageResource(your_image_here);
```

and in the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:id="@+id/llid">

    <TextView android:text="Client profile"
        android:id="@+id/ProfileName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    </TextView>    

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imagefield" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ImageView> 

    <TextView android:text="Specs"
        android:id="@+id/Specs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an ImageView into the xml, and if its not being used, make it invisible `(image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE))`. It may not show anything anyway when no image is set.

Comment: I think you may be over complicating something simple :)

Comment: I think you want to use View.GONE unless you want to leave an empty space.  You can insert using the index as well

Answer (score 0):

To get position of view in a view group

```
                val targetPosition = oldLL.indexOfChild(viewToAdd)
```

To add a view at a position in a view group

```
                newLL.addView(viewToAdd,targetPosition)
```