# How to merge one layout with another according to an specific view of the second layout?

Tags: android

I have two layouts. The first only has a `TextView` and the second has the below code.

I want to merge these two layouts in a way where the first layout displays the aforementioned `TextView` with the id "arry" of the second layout. I do this using a `FrameLayout` but for this I have to set top margin for the first layout.

I do not want to do this because the first layout will move up and down according to the screen size change. Can anybody tell me how to do this without setting such margin? I want to get the position of the `TextView` and after that I want to set the first layout programmatically. Here is the aforementioned code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.user_17.hashmapbasics.MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/arry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/arry1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.user_17.hashmapbasics.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/first_layout_id"
        layout="@layout/first_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/arry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/arry1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />
</LinearLayout>
```

where `first_layout` - your first layout `xml` file.

**Update:**

For insert layout programmatically You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6917818/6950238) answer of [antonyt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438140/antonyt) user:

> When adding a `View` to a `ViewGroup`, you can [specify an index](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int%29) which sets
>   the position of the view in the parent.
>
> You have two views and so (counting from zero) you would want to add
>   at the 1st position; just call `ll.addView(view, 1)`; to have it placed
>   in between the two TextViews.

In your case You should use `secondLayout.addView(firstLayout, 2)`, where `firstLayout` is `Layout` object for your first layout:

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
 View firstLayout= inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_layout, null, false);
 secondLayout.addView(firstLayout, 2);
```

Comment: can you tell me how to do the same pragmatically ?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6917818/6950238) answer

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `include` layout?

If your given layout xml file is, suppose "`your_layout.xml`"
Then you can go to you the layout where the `TextView` is then just below that add 
this line:

```
<include layout="@layout/your_layout"/>
```

For Example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/your_parent_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/app_bg"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">

<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/hello"
          android:padding="10dp" />

 <include layout="@layout/your_layout"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

For more to know, go to https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use "include" for merge two different layout

`<include
     android:id="@+id/layout"
     layout="@layout/first_layout"
     android:layout_gravity="center" />`